# What is the meaning of 花瓜？

Tags: phrase-meaning

Today I came across 4 成语 or phrases:

名扬天下
虎背熊腰
膀粗腰圆
骂了个花瓜

What is the meaning of 花瓜？

Comment: Though I know what 虎背熊腰 means, I sometimes like to see how Google Translates certain phrases to test its accuracy and I got "Huggy" LOL!!! So, always be wary.

Answer (score 1):

比喻頭破血流或被罵的體無完膚。例如：「臉上打得花瓜似的。」、「罵得他花瓜似的。」

It's a dialectal usage and it's the first time I see it.

[image]

Comment: Same. As a native Chinese speaker this is the first time I hear the phrase, and it occurs to me as very non-standard(dialectal). I'm quite surprise that it does occur in 老舍’s work though.